# CheckBox and id value to actionresult in kendo ui with ajax binding

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am developing a MVC with kendo UI grid. In which I have grid and one Button. Grid contains check-box. When We click on button check box value(true/false) and Record id should go to action result.

```
        using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Model"))
        {


            Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.Users)
                        .Name("grid")

                        .Columns(columns =>
                               {
                                   columns.Bound(o => o.UserName).Width("300px");
                                   columns.Bound(o => o.IsLicensed).Template(o =>
                                   {%><%: Html.CheckBox("license",o.IsLicensed)%> <%: Html.Hidden("id", o.UserId) %><%}).Width("200px");
                               })
                               .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
                               .Sortable(sorting => sorting.Enabled(true))
                               .Filterable(f => f.Enabled(true))
                               .Pageable(pageable => pageable
                                                        .Refresh(true)
                                                        .PageSizes(new int[] {10, 20, 50, 100})
                                                        .ButtonCount(5))             
                               .Render();           

%>

            <p>
                <input class="k-primary k-button" type="submit" value="Save" name="selectedValues"/>
            </p>
        <%
            Html.EndForm();
        }
        %>

    </div>
    <% });
```

And my actionresult looks as below

```
public ActionResult Update(string[] license, string[] id)
```

Now here I am using ajax binding and giving datasource. So I can't use Template. We need to use ClientTemplate. ClientTemplate code changes are shown as below.

```
                             .Columns(columns =>
                               {

                                   columns.Bound(o => o.UserName).Width("300px");
                                   columns.Bound(o => o.IsLicensed).Width("300px").ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' name='license' ${ IsLicensed == true ? checked='checked' : ''} enabled />" + "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='#= UserId#' />");
                               })
                               .DataSource(datasource => datasource.Ajax().Read(read => read.Action("Customers_Read", "UsersLicensing")).PageSize(10))
                               .Render();
```

In previous case when Update actionresult is called both parameter are array of 10 as pagesize is 10 and I can update database. But in this case(with ajax and clientTemplate) id parameter is coming as array of 10 items but license parameter depends on number of checkbox selected(if 3 checkbox is selected then license contains 3 element). So I can't make one to one mapping.

Can anybody help me with this or suggest any better idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to change your client template as such:

```
.ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' name='license' ${ IsLicensed == true ? checked='checked' : ''} enabled value='#= UserId#' />")
```

Put the `UserId` directly into the value of the checkbox. Then when you post, instead of getting an array of `"true"` you should get an array of the value (which is the UserId) for the checked items.

**Update**

If you want to be able to get both the checked and unchecked lists, then you can add the hidden field back to the `ClientTemplate`.

```
.ClientTemplate(
    "<input type='checkbox' name='license' ${ IsLicensed == true ? checked='checked' : ''} enabled value='#= UserId#' />" + 
    "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='#= UserId#' />"
)
```

Then when you post you will have an array of all of the IDs in `string[] id` and an array of the checked IDs in `string[] license`. Then to get the unchecked, you can use use `System.Linq` namespace and use [`Enumerable.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb300779%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

```
public ActionResult Update(string[] license, string[] id)
{
    //....
    var unchecked = id.Except(license).ToArray();
    //...
}
```

Comment: This solution can work if I can get array of id for particular.So I can generate one to one for particular page. Do you have any id about it?

Comment: I understand. When you post, you only get the checked values, but you need to know which ones are checked AND which ones are not. In that case, leave my code and add the hidden inputs back. Then when you post you will have an array of all IDs and an array of checked IDs. Simple matter then to do a LINQ `except` to get unchecked IDs. I will update my answer.

Comment: After updating comment i was playing with it and found same solution. Thanks for your suggestion of using Enumerable.Except.

Answer (score 1):

Try this....Worked for me

```
columns.Template(@<text></text>).
ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' class='chkbx'  onclick='chkRoleChkBox(this)' 
value='#=RoleId#'  # if (DefaultRoleflag == 'Y') { # disabled='disabled' # } #/>").Width(30);
```